# php Include function not working wamp

Tags: php, include, wamp

I'm fairly new to php, and I'm sure this is something simple. I have a php file named footer.php that contains the code I want at the end of every page, so I want to use an include function to do it. The file looks like this:

```
   <?php
   echo "<p>Copyright &copy; 1999-" . date("Y") . " W3Schools.com</p>";
   ?>
```

I then, in my main form, use an include statement like this:

```
    <html>
     <body>
     //other code//
      <?php include('footer.php');?>
    </body>
   </html>
```

The //other code// is stuff that isn't relevant and works fine.

I have my wamp server on, and both files are in the www folder in it. Any ideas why the include footer isn't showing up in my main file? I'm not getting any error messages in the log. Do I need to go into phpmyadmin or something?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Try using `require('footer.php');` and see if you get an error. And if so what is the error?

Comment: can you please check you error log. I don't see anything wrong on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Does your main file have a .php extension? If it is set to for instance index.html, the PHP include will not be executed and you will just see the HTML with no errors logged.

Comment: The main file is a php file, not a HTML file.

Comment: Given the information provided your include should work properly. That is assuming you have a main file with a .php extension and another file in the directory called footer.php which PHP has permissions to access. Here is an example with the setup as you describe working properly. http://goo.gl/ckS47c.

Answer (score 0):

Is your main form file saved with a .php extension?

You can also try

```
<?php require_once "footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: I used phpstorm, and created a new php file with the name footer. So, in the folder it just says footer, but it is php, not html. The same for the main form file.

Comment: PHP files created in phpstorm are displayed in the project view with their .php extension.